# why can't i edit this question?

Tags: support, editing

i usually think that i have enough rep to directly edit questions on the SP.SE site.  but i cannot edit [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37548/fourier-transform) because someone with less rep has an edit in the approval queue.

now my *"authority"* to edit questions should have nothing to do with whether or not someone else has an edit pending.  why can't i just edit the damn thing?

Answer (score 1):

rb-j, that seems to be standard operating procedure for all Stack Exchange sites. See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/131640) for why you may not be able to edit a question:

> There are a handful of conditions where we will stop accepting suggested edits:
>
> - A large number of suggested edits by you were rejected in the past week (at least 5 more than one-third of your accepted edits).
> - We are out of empty slots in the queue (40, with several exceptions. See here for details)
> - **There is an edit to a particular post that was not approved yet.**
> - You are not logged in and the post is less than 10 minutes old.
> - You are on a child meta.
>
> In the past no "edit" link would be shown at all; since July 2012 the edit link is disabled and the mouse hover tooltip will explain why an edit cannot be suggested, like "Account is not allowed to suggest edits".

**Emphasis** mine.

---

edit from r b-j:

this doesn't make sense.  see, i can just edit this now and the change take place instantly, because i have enough rep to do so.

but if someone with **in**sufficient rep tried to edit this, it goes into the queue, but that prevents **me** from editing.  that should be unrelated.

Comment: Ours is not to question why....

Comment: The rule prevents edit conflicts I think.